# How to add button over image on tap

Tags: swift

So, I want to add a button over existing image, but what I want is - when I tap on map (in this case), I want this red button to show up at the place where I tapped. I want it in SWIFT.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oei04rsmf2xh99/Screenshot%202015-02-20%2013.42.17.png?dl=0

Comment: What have you tried? You have to set userInteractionEnabled to True to your UIImage, you can use touchesBegan to detect the touch, then get the position (if it's inside the view) and show your button.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer -> Get tap locationInView -> create button at location. No offense but it sounds like you didn't even try to figure this out yourself.

Comment: I'm still newbie in swift, so... :/